# Wait until async call has finished - Ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm working in Ionic2 and I have this problem:
In my component there is `drawPlayer` method which retrieves data from firebase database.

Here is its code:

```
drawPlayer(){
    this.playerData.drawThePlayer().on('value', snapshot => {
      // some stuff
    });
    return this.drawnPlayer;   // returns the player name
}
```

In the same file (component) inside `ngOnInit` function I need to call `drawPlayer()` and I do:

```
ngOnInit(){
let myVar = this.drawPlayer();
console.log("test: "+myVar);
}
```

If I inspect the console I read `test: undefined`, if I go back and return to that page again, I see `test: a correct value`. I think this is because of that `drawPlayer()` is an asyncronous call and when I do `console.log` it hasn't returned the result yet.

So, how can I `console.log` only after `drawPlayer()` has finished?

/*****************************************************************************/

**EDIT:** (after httpNick answer)

Now I have this `drawPlayer()` method with complete code (this.drawnPlayer is defined out of these methods, globally):

```
drawPlayer(cb){
    this.playerData.drawThePlayer().on('value', snapshot => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      for (var key in data){
            this.drawnPlayer = String(data[key].lastName);
            console.log("playerName: "+this.drawnPlayer);
      }
    });
    console.log("test: "+this.drawnPlayer);
    cb(this.drawnPlayer);   // returns the player name
}
```

ngOnInit() is like this:

```
this.drawPlayer(function(valueFromDrawPlayer) {
    console.log("callback result: "+valueFromDrawPlayer);
});
console.log("after the callback");
```

When I run the app this is what I see in browser console:

```
test: undefined
callback result: undefined
after the callback
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
playerName: John
```

But I expect to read this:

```
playerName: John
test: John
callback result: John
after the callback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where `this.drawnPlayer` comes from, but if you pass in a callback function to `drawPlayer` you can call that after the async code has finished running to be able to log the return value.

```
drawPlayer(cb){
    this.playerData.drawThePlayer().on('value', snapshot => {
      // some stuff
    });
    cb(this.drawnPlayer);   // returns the player name
}
ngOnInit(){
    drawPlayer((x) => { console.log(x) });
}
```

Last line can be rewritten to this as well:

```
drawPlayer(function(valueFromDrawPlayer) {
    console.log(valueFromDrawPlayer);
});
```

**EDIT AFTER SEEING FULL CODE:**

```
drawPlayer(cb){
    this.playerData.drawThePlayer().on('value', snapshot => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      for (var key in data){
            this.drawnPlayer = String(data[key].lastName);
            console.log("playerName: "+this.drawnPlayer);
            cb(this.drawnPlayer);   // returns the player name
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you explain me the last line: drawPlayer((x) => { console.log(x) });

And What is 'x'?

Comment: I updated my answer to show what it can be rewritten as. Basically x is my poorly named parameter for the anonymous callback function that you will pass into `drawPlayer`. So in the above case, `cb(this.drawnPlayer);` would pass `this.drawnPlayer` into the function as `x`. If you want to read more on the syntax I used for that line, it is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thank you. should I put that "last line" inside ngOnInit method? Sorry if the question seems dummy. I'll look at callbacks deeper as soon as I'll have time

Comment: I've done as you said but I still have problems. I've edited the question with the results/errors I get

Comment: Looking at the full code you posted now, you will want to call the callback within your `.on('value', snapshot => { }` callback function so that you make sure this.drawnPlayer is set. That is why your `console.log("playerName: "+this.drawnPlayer);` is showing a non-undefined value. See my updated answer

Answer (score -2):

Try making an synchronous wrapper around the async call. Generally you would not want to do this because it blocks the entire thread pool. If it is a must block the async return method using a wait. It essentially defeats the purpose of using an async in the first place.

```
   public static whatever CallAndWaitAsync()
   {
       task.Wait(); // Block thread until completed
       var result = task.Result;
       return result;
   }
```